# TypeError from merge pandas DataFrame on columns when item in columns is list

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, merge, typeerror

I got `TypeError: type object argument after * must be an iterable, not itertools.imap` for doing `pd.merge` 2 dataframes `df1` and `df_iden`on the columns `'allmzidx'` where data is list

Simplified data:

```
# df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1110],'b':[1135],'c':[1160]})
df1['allmzidx'] = df1.values.tolist()
df1['allmzidx'] = df1.allmzidx.sort_values()

# df_iden is created from list of lists of tuples
alliden_tuple2 = [[('a2','b2',[1736, 1761, 1786]),('a12','b12',[1110, 1135, 1160])],[('a2','b2',[1736, 1761, 1786]  ),('a12','b12',[1110, 1135, 1160])]]
# for each list of tuples
for index, each_iden in enumerate(alliden_tuple2):
    df_iden = pd.DataFrame(each_iden, columns=['int','mztop3','allmzidx'])
    df_iden = pd.merge(df_iden, df1, how='left', on='allmzidx')
```

Why I can't merge the dataframes on the '`allmzidx`' as `list` here?

**update** Changing data to tuple works but I appreciate if someone may add the additional reasons why `list` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need convert `list`s to `tuple`s:

```
df1['allmzidx'] = df1['allmzidx'].apply(tuple)

for index, each_iden in enumerate(alliden_tuple2):
    df_iden = pd.DataFrame(each_iden, columns=['int','mztop3','allmzidx'])
    df_iden['allmzidx'] = df_iden['allmzidx'].apply(tuple)
    df_iden = pd.merge(df_iden, df1, how='left', on='allmzidx')
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But why I have to change both of them to `tuple`? I try to merge them in `list` for very long time. Why `list` doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @Jan - Hmm, I am not pandas developer, but maybe because lists are mutable and tuples not. Or simplier it is not implemented.

Comment: @Jan - I try ask question about reason, I hope some pandas dev explain it. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49425936/2901002)