# Merge list column fail

Tags: python, list, pandas, merge, multiple-columns

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('ab'), 'b':[[1,2],[4,5]]})
print (df1)
   a       b
0  a  [1, 2]
1  b  [4, 5]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':list('cd'), 'b':[[1,7],[4,5]]})
print (df2)
        b  c
0  [1, 7]  c
1  [4, 5]  d
```

I try merge by column `b` with `list`s:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='b')
```

> TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not map

I find solution with convert columns to tuples:

```
df1['b'] = df1['b'].apply(tuple)
df2['b'] = df2['b'].apply(tuple)

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='b')
print (df)
   a       b  c
0  b  (4, 5)  d
```

But why `merge` with `list`s columns failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try your example in python3.6

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('ab'), 'b':[[1,2],[4,5]]})
print (df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':list('cd'), 'b':[[1,7],[4,5]]})
print (df2)

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='b')
```

I get the (final) error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Because for merging, the column to merge on needs to be hashable.
The same error is given, if you try to hash one of your values

```
hash([1,7])
```

Converting the values to tuple makes them hashable

```
print(hash((1,7)))

1303117175
```

That's why mergeing column with lists is not possible. No hash.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about it, but it seems that using a dict instead of a list such as:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('ab'), 'b':[{1:2},{4:5}]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':list('cd'), 'b':[{1:7},{4:5}]})
```

or set:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('ab'), 'b':[{1,2},{4,5}]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':list('cd'), 'b':[{1,7},{4,5}]})
```

you will get the same error.

So I believe that merge with `list` columns failed because they are **mutable** while `tuble` are not

Comment: Thank you for answer, do you think it is per design?

Comment: @jezrael what is the efficient way to convert whole df to lower case?

Comment: @pyd - Not so easy, all columns are strings? `df = df.stack().str.lower().unstack()` should works.